# How to add translation for Category name in Prestashop?

Tags: translation, prestashop

I understand that when we add a new word in the template using smarty templates syntax like

```
{l s="Example"}
```

Will show up for translation in the admin control panel translation page but how can I add translations for Category names, which are added from the admin control panel and not in the template, template simply gets the categories from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to modify your categories, next to the name input field you will see flags, just click and modify corresponding translation.

[image]